# How to trim view field to height or number of lines?

Tags: views, entities

I have a div with a fixed height and want to display a view field.  When the content overflows the div, I'd like an elipsis to click for more.

CSS can handle overflow and hide it (and overflow-text can handle a single line) but I have to estimate everyting for number of lines since words can be an arbitrary length.  Sure views with or without [the smart trim module](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_trim) can handle words or characters, but I need to estimate the number of lines or, ideally, **I'd like the trim based on the max-height of a div**.

The [Smart Trim maintainer suggested a CSS library](https://www.drupal.org/node/2565187#comment-10306655) which may help but does not solve the problem.

I imagine that views text overflow based on height is a common problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to handle this with Drupal modules, I suggest you use  [Ellipsis](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) in your Style( style the result rows items with `Ellipsis` .

You can read below help content :

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922739/limit-text-length-to-n-lines-using-css)

[link2](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: All roads seem to lead back to the css library but even so, as far as i can tell, they will not let you make the ellipsis into an anchor to link back to the content or other view.  How do most people handle a variable amount of summary text in a fixed height div?  I feel like I must be missing something big :)

Comment: @Sonicthoughts you can handle it with link2 help,you just need add this css properties to your view item  :)